# Can you parse a JSON String to an Table when you have a volatile data source?

Tags: json, mongodb, oracle

I have a requirement to ingest `JSON` files exported from `MongoDB` and load them into an `Oracle` relational database. I have an `Oracle 12c` instance to make use of the `JSON parser` functionality.

While I can parse `CLOBs` into tables when I know the structure of the data coming in, this data source is volatile and columns can be added, moved or removed at a moment's notice by the front end developers. I have no control or influence over the source system so I cannot get anything more stable.

My need is to take the ingested `CLOB` and generate a source table that can be read by `Informatica Powercenter 9.1` in whatever structure is made available to me.

Is this possible? I know I can use the `JSON_TABLE` command in `Oracle` to convert the `CLOB` to a table, but as far as I can see this requires you to know the structure of the data to load into a table. As this is needs to be an automated process I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're lucky enough to be on 12.2, there's an easy way to do this: with the [JSON Data Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C).

This allows you to expose attributes of a JSON document as virtual columns on a table. To use it, there's a couple of setup steps:

- Add an "is json" check constraint to the column
- Create a JSON search index

The index needs to have the "dataguide on" parameter:

```
create table t (
  doc varchar2(1000) check ( doc is json )
);

insert into t values ('{"attr1": "value1"}');
commit;

create search index i on t ( doc ) for json 
  parameters ('dataguide on change add_vc');
```

With these in place, you can add the virtual columns like so:

```
begin
  dbms_json.add_virtual_columns (
    't', 'doc',
    dbms_json.get_index_dataguide('t', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical)
  );
end;
/

select * from t;

DOC                   DOC$attr1   
{"attr1": "value1"}   value1
```

So what's the relevance of the "change add_vc" index parameter?

This adds virtual columns to your tables based on the input documents on commit!

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr2": "value2"}');
commit;

select * from t;

DOC                   DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   
{"attr1": "value1"}   value1      <null>      
{"attr2": "value2"}   <null>      value2
```

This will add some overhead every time you insert new documents. So I'd be wary of using "change add_vc". And schedule a job to add columns instead.

If you end up with lots of deprecated attributes you want to ignore, you can easily get rid the virtual columns with a procedure call:

```
exec dbms_json.drop_virtual_columns ( 't', 'doc' );
select * from t;

DOC                   
{"attr1": "value1"}   
{"attr2": "value2"}
```

So that's all very well and good for scalar attributes. But what about arrays?

Sadly these won't appear as virtual columns:

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr3": ["value3", "value4"]}');
commit;

select * from t;

DOC                               
{"attr1": "value1"}               
{"attr2": "value2"}               
{"attr3": ["value3", "value4"]}
```

But you create a view which exposes these:

```
begin
  DBMS_JSON.create_view (
    't_v', 't', 'doc',
    dbms_json.get_index_dataguide(
      't', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical
    )
  );
end;
/

select * from t_v;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             
value1      <null>      <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]
```

This won't automatically update if you add new attributes, but you can rebuild the view easily enough:

```
insert into t (doc) values ('{"attr4": ["value5", "value6"]}');
commit;

select * from t_v;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             
value1      <null>      <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]   
<null>      <null>      <null>  

begin
  DBMS_JSON.create_view (
    't_v', 't', 'doc',
    dbms_json.get_index_dataguide(
      't', 'doc', dbms_json.format_hierarchical
    )
  );
end;
/

select * from t_v;

DOC$attr1   DOC$attr2   DOC$attr3             DOC$attr4             
value1      <null>      <null>                <null>                
<null>      value2      <null>                <null>                
<null>      <null>      ["value3","value4"]   <null>                
<null>      <null>      <null>                ["value5","value6"]
```

Remember: you need to be on 12.2 higher to use this. I'm not aware of a simple solution to do this in 12.1.

[APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635) includes a get_members function which you can use to find the attributes within a document. But you'll have to build something else to expose these to another client.

Comment: Hi Chris, that's a fantastic solution. I've just checked, though, and I'm on 12.1. Back to the drawing board I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks, sadly I think the 12.1 solution will be far more complicated... :/